# How can i search any string value from a manipulated coloumn of table in oracle sql

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, dml

How can I search any string value from a manipulated column of table like:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(DESCR,1,8) AS MYDES FROM STATION WHERE descr='ABERDEEN';
```

I want to search 'ABERDEEN' from `SUBSTR(DESCR,1,8)` or 'MYDES' column but in my case 'ABERDEEN' is still searched from DESCR column. How can I search it from the new manipulated 'MYDES' column (oracle, sql)?

Comment: Put the substr directly in the where clause. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the rows which has the **substr** as `ABERDEEN` in the column `descr`, then use the function in the **filter predicate**.

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM STATION WHERE SUBSTR(DESCR,1,8)='ABERDEEN';
```

To include the new column in the output along with other columns,

```
SELECT t.*,
  SUBSTR(DESCR,1,8) AS MYDES
FROM STATION
WHERE SUBSTR(DESCR,1,8)='ABERDEEN';
```

Comment: @VinayakDwivedi You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE in where as below :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(DESCR,1,8) AS MYDES FROM STATION WHERE descr like 'ABERDEEN%';
```

Comment: this is acceptable but not fully convincing becaz in this case it will check more than one value